# Angularjs: how load model in lazy mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, ng-bind

I want to load some data in lazy mode.
In particular, suppose I have an object like this one:

```
$scope.person = {
   name: 'Stefano',
   surname: 'Rossi',
   address: 'Orange Road',
   city: { 
      clazz: 'foo.bar.City',
      id: 5, 
      lazy: true 
  }
}
```

With angular I can bind the first three properties to an html tag without problem.

```
<input ng-model="person.name">
<input ng-model="person.surname">
<input ng-model="person.address">
```

And it works well.

But suppose that I want to add a decode of city, I would be possible interact ngBinding or ngModel for test if the object is lazy, so with a promise get the real value (I think get by $http service )

I try extend ngmodel but not have the correct $scope...

https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/13/

Anybody knows how to interact with ngmodel o ngbinding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly but if you want to fetch data from somewhere else you would generally do that in a controller, to handle the promise and once it is resolved you add it to the scope, from where it will be automatically available on the view (via 2 way data binding).

Answer (score 1):

Due to two-way data binding models could be lazy loaded once mounted on the view.
Here is a rough example loading the model upon an event giving you the ability to make any additional changes.

```
$scope.loadlater = function() {
    $scope.person = {
      name: 'Stefano',
      surname: 'Rossi',
      address: 'Orange Road',
      city: {
        clazz: 'foo.bar.City',
        id: 5,
        lazy: true
      }
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qq4gqn6t/14/